# AttributeError: 'Twython' object has no attribute 'destroy_message'

Tags: python, twitter, twython

Within the last 2 weeks or so one of my Twitter cleanup scripts stopped working. It appears that there is no longer an attribute for destroy_message which is used to delete sent DMs.  Was this removed or renamed?  Here is my code and the error.

```
for tweet in tweets:
           print "Deleting: " + tweet["text"]
           result = self._api.destroy_message(id = tweet["id"])
```

Here is the error:

```
Getting sent DMs....
Deleting: Sure no problem
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "scrub_twitter.py", line 127, in <module>
obj.delete_sent_dms()
File "scrub_twitter.py", line 102, in delete_sent_dms
result = self._api.destroy_message(id = tweet["id"])
AttributeError: 'Twython' object has no attribute 'destroy_message'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has been renamed to:

```
destroy_direct_message(**params)
```

[See here.](https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=destroy#twython.Twython.destroy_direct_message)

Comment: Thank you sir, I always wondered why the sent and received destroy was not combined. That fixed it.